# Serious yet entertaining/humorous question deleted somehow. Can I find my old post?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

As a former biologist, I had a serious question about the worst-case implications of eating food found on the street, as in what types of poisons would be likely and what their effects might be. From that, I could determine probable courses of treatment, including informing a hospital etc.

I got some up votes, and people seemed to enjoy the post, as that type of question, while serious, is part of my inquisitive, and often humorous nature.

However, the question mysteriously disappeared without notification (Or I missed it). Whence and why did this happen?

This question was asked sometime around early 2013

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to go into your profile and see the question. If this is not possible due to limited reputation, here a few facts:

- The question was closed as off-topic.
- It wasn't well received, you got three downvotes on it.
- It got automatically deleted by the system, as this happens with all closed questions, which have no or negative votes and no answers. See here for more information. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) for details.

So nothing unusual happened here.

Comment: Makes sense. What's the required reputation to see a deleted question?

Comment: See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted) for details. The direct link to your question (since it is older than 60 days) is [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/5044/found-pristine-food-on-the-street-need-a-good-strategy-for-poison-testing).